# Customize colors in beamer Madrid theme

Tags: beamer, color

I have been trying to customize color themes in Madrid beamer theme for slide sections. I have checked the beamercolorthemedefault.sty file looking for the properties I should change to do so, and I was able to modify the frame title background:

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=green!40!black}
```

Also I could change it back with this:

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=beamer@blendedblue}
```

So far, I could not change the colors of the boxes at the bottom, which contains, author, short title, etc.. I have been wondering which color definitions are related to those, since I had changed couple of them I thought they would, with no success. I am a bit confused with the parental system of the color definition as well. Several of those are just link to another which is already defined like following:

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=titlelike}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
```

I am not sure where shall I interrupt this chain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to dig into the `Madrid` theme in order to see what it sets for the colours. Looking at [`beamerthemeMadrid.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeMadrid.sty), we see it uses the following additional themes:

```
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
```

While one might think the colours are defined in [`beamercolorthemewhale.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemewhale.sty) and [`beamercolorthemeorchid.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemeorchid.sty), this is only partially true. Let's look at the construction of the `footline` in [`beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty):

```
\setbeamercolor*{author in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{title in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamercolor*{date in head/foot}{parent=palette primary}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

It seems to construct 3 boxes with the left using colour `author in head/foot` (`parent=palette tertiary`), the centre using colour `title in head/foot` (`parent=palette secondary`) and the right using colour `date in head/foot` (`parent=palette primary`). So, change the aforementioned colours.

I'd rather suggest changing the base colour, and letting the other theme colours follow relative to it. For example, change `beamer@blendedblue`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Madrid}

% Change base colour beamer@blendedblue (originally RGB: 0.2,0.2,0.7)
\colorlet{beamer@blendedblue}{green!40!black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
  This is some frame content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```